# Override Meta in ModelForm

Tags: python, django, forms

If I have:

```
class MCQuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MultipleChoiceQuestion
        fields = ('prompt',)
```

Can I override `class Meta` to change `model` to some other model? For instance:

```
class Meta:
    model = models.EssayQuestion
```

EDIT:

I had to add that I need to make this override at runtime, the model class will come from the result in views' logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean at runtime? Yes, you can. Here is a simple way to do it:

```
def get_question_form(conditional_model):
    class MCQuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = conditional_model
            ...
    return MCQuestionForm
```

Then in your view, you can override the `get_form_class` method and use that function to return the class with whatever model you want on it.

If you're using function-based views, it might look something like this:

```
def my_view(request):
    model = MultipleChoiceQuestion
    if some_condition:
        model = EssayQuestion
    form = get_question_form(model)
    # now do stuff with form...
```

If you're using class-based views, it might look something like this:

```
from django.views.generic import FormView

class MyView(FormView):
    ...
    def get_form_class(self):
        model = MultipleChoiceQuestion
        if some_condition:
            model = EssayQuestion
        return get_question_form(model)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks denvaar! Sorry I have just started messing with django. Can you please a little bit elaborate on your answer

Comment: @SaidAkh Sure, but I think I need to understand what you're trying to do a little better in order to provide something meaningful.

Comment: Depending on views logic, I will supply different models to `ModelForm` at runtime.

Comment: @SaidAkh have a look at my updated answer, hopefully that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Have a look at [Form Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#form-inheritance]) in django documentation.

You can create a new form for `EssayQuestion` and inherit `MCQuestionForm.Meta` in `Meta` inner class:

```
class EssayQuestionForm(MCQuestionForm):

    class Meta(MCQuestionForm.Meta):
        model = models.EssayQuestion
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `modelform_factory` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/models/#modelform-factory

```
from django.forms.models import modelform_factory

if condition:
    model = models.MultipleChoiceQuestion
else:
    model = models.EssayQuestion

runtimeform_class = modelform_factory(model, fields=(...), )
```