# Can I specify or change fields to use in a ModelFrom from within my Views.py?

Tags: django, django-forms

Let's say I have the following ModelForm:

forms.py

```
class JournalEntryForm(ModelForm):
    def clean_date(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['date']
        # Some validation...
        return data
    class Meta:
        model = JournalEntry
        fields = ['user','date','description']
        widgets = {'date': DateTypeInput()}
```

I want to reuse the above modelform in several views. But the different views require different fields to be used from the model form. Is there a way I can "over ride" the fields in the ModelForm meta?

I tried this:

```
@login_required
def entries_update(request, pk):
    journal_entry = get_object_or_404(JournalEntry, pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        journal_entry_form = JournalEntryForm(request.POST, instance=journal_entry)
        journal_entry_form.fields = ['date','description'] # Just testing !
        if journal_entry_form.is_valid():
            journal_entry_form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Journal entry successfully updated.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('journal:entries_show_detail', kwargs={'pk': journal_entry.id}) )
    return render(request, 'journal/entries_update.html',{'journal_entry': journal_entry, 'journal_entry_form': journal_entry_form, })
```

I get an error:

```
Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

The end of the traceback:

```
C:\Users\Philip\CodeRepos\Acacia2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py in _clean_fields
        for name, field in self.fields.items(): …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
self    
<JournalEntryForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(date;description)>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a number of ways to achieve what your are aiming at. The easiest approach would be to define a BaseForm class with different Meta and pick the appropriate Form in your views:

```
class JournalEntryForm(ModelForm):
    def clean_date(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['date']
        # Some validation...
        return data
    class Meta:
        model = JournalEntry
        fields = ['user','date','description']
        widgets = {'date': DateTypeInput()}

class JournalEntryForm2(JournalEntryForm):
    class Meta:
        model = JournalEntry
        fields = ['date','description']
        widgets = {'date': DateTypeInput()}
```

Another quite nice approach is defining a function to create your required form at runtime as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880951/override-meta-in-modelform):

```
def get_journal_form(myfields):
    class JournalEntryForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = JournalEntry
            fields = myfields
    return JournalEntryForm
```

and create the form in your view based on whatever condition

```
FormClass = get_journal_form(['date', 'description'])
```

A third approach could be overidng the `'__init__'` method of your form, passing your unwanted fields to the `__init__`

class JournalEntryForm(ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = JournalEntry
    fields = ['user', 'date', 'description']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    unwanted_fields = kwargs.pop('unwanted_fields')
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for f in unwanted_fields:
        self.fields.pop(f)
```